# What is the quickest way to get from Naples to Ljubljana?

Tags: air-travel, trains, italy, buses, slovenia

I'm trying to book a holiday where we need to travel from Naples, Italy to Ljubljana, Slovenia on July 6th 2020.

I've looked at flying from Naples to Trieste, then getting a bus to Ljubljana, but I'm worried about missing the bus if the flight is delayed and it's still quite expensive and takes a long time.

I'm happy to fly/train/bus/drive. What's the quickest way to get from Naples to Ljubljana?

Comment: Please see [Rome2rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Naples/Ljubljana).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be too early to see and book all specific options. Airlines may add routes or schedules yet and buses usually don't publish schedules more than a half a year in advance (often even less).

1. Fly direct to Trieste (1:20) + bus to Ljubljana (1:44)

   - [Volotea](https://www.volotea.com) flies direct, but only shows schedules through July 2nd 2020. They have a 1:20 flight on Monday June 29th for €47. It may be worth contacting them to see if they are terminating the route or if schedules have just not been released yet.
   - Several [bus lines run between Trieste and Ljubljana](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules-results/u21g9w/u24q40?outbound_date=2020-03-30&adults=1&origin_location[5169]=true), but looks like only one departs the airport (though the July schedule isn't out yet). It's tight connection to that flight: risky but very quick.
2. Fly direct to Treviso (1:20) + bus to Ljubljana (2:30)

   - Ryanair has two direct flights on July 6th. 7am and 7pm for €30-40. They call the airport "Venice Treviso"
   - [DRD Turizem, GoOpti, Nomago and TripstAir](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules-results/u20ey3/u24q40?outbound_date=2020-03-30&adults=1&origin_location[42180]=true&origin_location[50712]=true&destination_location[5168]=true&destination_location[17632]=true&destination_location[50313]=true) all run from TSF Airport to Ljubljana, again the July schedule isn't out yet but you should be able to find a decent connection with frequent departures.
3. Fly direct to Venice Marco Polo (1:20) + bus to Ljubljana (2:49)

   - easyJet has two direct flights on July 6th. 7am and 7pm for €25.
   - [DRD Turizem, GoOpti, Nomago, TripstAir and FlixBus](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules-results/u20f2x/u24q40?outbound_date=2020-03-30&adults=1&origin_location[5171]=true) all run from VCE Airport to Ljubljana, again the July schedule isn't out yet but you should be able to find a decent connection with frequent departures.

Full disclosure: I work for Busbud, the site showing various bus lines.

Comment: Pretty solid answer. Just adding that you can fly to Trieste (airport is far out of the city) and rent a car and drive to Ljubljana. It seems safer than bus but more expensive.

Comment: I don't know about the air or bus connections to Klagenfurt, but the drive from Klagenfurt airport to Ljubljana is only about ten minutes longer than from the Trieste airport.  I just went to check the Adria Airways route map and found that they went bankrupt this week.  Presumably other airlines may add some service to Ljubljana in response.

Answer (score 1):

From [Rome2rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Naples/Ljubljana), the quickest way is to take a flight from Naples to Trieste (TRS) ans then a 1 hour 15 minute shuttle to Ljubljana.